# Altering the size of a data type uisng json file or .jh file - Jhipster entity generation

Tags: jhipster, liquibase

Modifying an entity by changing the data type size, by changing the respective .json file or .jh file does not seem to work. The changelog file generated does not have changeset entry.

I tried following with jhipster version (v4.14.1)

1. `jhipster entity entityName` (after changing the entityName.json -- edited the size of datatype varchar).
2. `jhipster import-jdl jdlfile.jh`(after changing the size of datatype varchar for respective entity).

I had to manually change the "changelog" file. Interestingly, all other related files like "entity-dialog.html" get changed to reflect the size.

Json file :

```html
{
    "fluentMethods": true,
    "relationships": [
        {
            "relationshipName": "diff_table",
            "otherEntityName": "diff_table",
            "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
            "otherEntityField": "id"
        }
    ],
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldName": "ab",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "maxlength"
            ],
            "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 50
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "abc",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "maxlength"
            ],
            "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 50
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "abc",
            "fieldType": "XYZ",
            "fieldValues": "A,B,C,D,E,F"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "abd",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "maxlength"
            ],
            "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 35
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "abe",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "maxlength"
            ],
            "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 35
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "abf",
            "fieldType": "LocalDate"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "abs",
            "fieldType": "LocalDate"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "abh",
            "fieldType": "LocalDate"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "abj",
            "fieldType": "LocalDate"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "abk",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "maxlength"
            ],
            "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 50
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "abkk",
            "fieldType": "Long"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "abcc",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "maxlength"
            ],
            "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 100
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "abbc",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "maxlength"
            ],
            "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 100
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "abbc",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "maxlength"
            ],
            "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 20
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "amc",
            "fieldType": "Boolean"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "abad",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "maxlength"
            ],
            "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 10
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "amms",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "maxlength"
            ],
            "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 50
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "anda",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "maxlength"
            ],
            "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 200
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "amdmdd",
            "fieldType": "LocalDate"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "ajdd",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "maxlength"
            ],
            "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 20
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "adnkd",
            "fieldType": "Boolean"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "andand",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "maxlength"
            ],
            "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 300
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "addad",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "maxlength"
            ],
            "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 50
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "dadad",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "maxlength"
            ],
            "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 50
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "dadad",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "maxlength"
            ],
            "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 50
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "dad",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "maxlength"
            ],
            "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 10
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "dad",
            "fieldType": "Long"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "dada",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "maxlength"
            ],
            "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 100
        }
    ],
    "changelogDate": "20180325122923",
    "entityTableName": "table_name",
    "dto": "mapstruct",
    "pagination": "pagination",
    "service": "no",
    "jpaMetamodelFiltering": false
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: could you please provide more details? Like which command you ran, which version, entity definition.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou, added. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at generator's code, I can't understand how it would not work. Could you show the entity definition as .json?
 https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/v4.x_maintenance/generators/entity-server/templates/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/_added_entity.xml#L62-L65

Comment: At first when I tried, I did overwrite the changelog file added_entity. But when I built the code it mentioned the checksum issue. Then next time I did not override and did a mvn liquibase:diff. I think I am doing something wrong as the generator code looks fine above.